# Dygraphs - How do I restrict drawing to canvas

Tags: callback, dygraphs

I have a graph where I am using underlays to draw vertical lines between the points. I have a line of code that restricts these vertical lines to NOT draw outside the active canvas. But when I use this underlayCallback, the 'points' are still drawn outside the canvas. If I remove my underlayCallback, the points are restricted to the canvas as one would expect. Here is what they look like and my code. (Sorry, the site is too secure to provide working sample.)

```
g[i] = new Dygraph(thisdiv, mylines, {
            labels: graphlbls[i],
            ylabel: graphunits[i].capitalizeFirstLetter(),
            xlabel: '',
            xLabelHeight:15,
            yLabelWidth:15,
            rightGap: 5,
            labelsDivStyles: {
                'text-align': 'right',
                'background': 'none'
            },
            colors: ['#D48513','#1D6EB5'],
            title: graphtitles[i],
            titleHeight:23,
            drawPoints: true,
            showRoller: false,
            drawXGrid: false,
            drawYGrid: true,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            pointSize: 4,
            highlightCircleSize: 6,
            gridLineColor: "#ddd",
            axisLabelFontSize: 12,
            xAxisHeight: 20,
            valueRange: [minval, maxval],
            rangeSelectorHeight: 30,
            showRangeSelector: true,
            rangeSelectorPlotFillColor: '#ffffff',
            rangeSelectorPlotStrokeColor: '#ffffff',
            interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
            axes: {
                x: {
                    valueFormatter: function (ms) {
                        var d = new Date(ms);
                        var day = "0"+d.getDate();
                        var month = "0"+(d.getMonth()+1);
                        var year = d.getFullYear();
                        var hour = "0"+ d.getHours();
                        var min = "0"+d.getMinutes();
                        var p = "AM";
                        if (hour > 12) { p = "PM"; hour = hour - 12; }
                        if (df == 0) var dd = month.slice(-2)+"/"+day.slice(-2)+"/"+year;
                        if (df == 1) var dd = day.slice(-2)+"/"+month.slice(-2)+"/"+year;
                        if (tf == 0) var tt = hour.slice(-2)+":"+min.slice(-2)+" "+p+" ";
                        if (tf == 1) var tt = hour.slice(-2)+":"+min.slice(-2)+" ";
                        return dd + " - " + tt;
                    }
                }
            },
            underlayCallback: function(ctx, area, g) {
                //if (typeof(g[i]) == 'undefined') return;  // won't be set on the initial draw.
                var range = g.xAxisRange();
                var rows = g.numRows();

                // get max and min y
                for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    miny = 99999;
                    maxy = -99999;
                    xx = g.getValue(i,0);
                    if (xx < range[0] || xx > range[1]) continue;   // constrain to graph canvas
                    for (var j=1; j<= range.length; j++) {
                        if (g.getValue(i,j) <= miny) miny = g.getValue(i,j);
                        if (g.getValue(i,j) >= maxy) maxy = g.getValue(i,j);
                    }
                    p1 = g.toDomCoords(xx, miny);
                    p2 = g.toDomCoords(xx, maxy);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(192,192,224,1)";
                    ctx.lineWidth = 1.0;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(p1[0], p1[1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(p2[0], p2[1]);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `ctx.restore()` many times without corresponding calls to `ctx.save()`. This pops off dygraphs' own drawing context, including the clipping rectangle. Make one call to save at the top of your underlayCallback and one to restore at the end.

Stepping back a bit, what you're doing might be easier with a custom plotter, rather than an underlayCallback.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Dan, can you take a look at this one? Thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362757/how-do-i-leave-the-clicked-point-highlighted-in-dygraphs